# Does an SWF StartTimer/TimerFired have to run on the same Decider?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-swf

I'm running into an issue where it appears as though, when I `StartTimer` say for 10s then intentionally quit my decider and restart it, 10+ seconds will elapse with no event posted to my newly restarted Decider.  If I get the execution history of the workflow, the `TimerFired` event is there.

I am using the **boto3** python library and my Decider, after it starts is blocking by waiting on:

```
while True:
    swf.poll_for_decision_task(**kwargs)
```

I notice that the **startTimerDecisionAttributes** do not require a task list and my **poll_for_decisison_task** does include a task list, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

If I do not stop the decider after it does the `StartTimer`, the `TimerFired` event does come through.

Given it is only on decider restart that I see this behavior, I am curious if there is a requirement that the same decider handles the `TimerFired`

Comment: Ahhh it appears that setting `taskStartToCloseTimeout` on `start_workflow_execution` appears to make a difference. I was setting it to "NONE" and I just changed it. I will need to do some more testing to confirm

Comment: Indeed taskStartToCloseTimeout for workflow should be pretty low to ensure that decision tasks are redelivered in a timely manner.